# Why the sudden flurry of edits?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing

The "hot" page is taking a bit of a beating these past couple of days. I monitor the "questions" page as well, but I spend a lot of time on the "hot" page because it tells me who's answering (there are some names that tell me up front that the question has been well and truly answered before I get there). Lately, though, it's been dredging up the Thames and pushing the current crop of questions off the front page.

Surely there must be a way of preventing something like a retag of a six-month-old question with an accepted answer from becoming "hot". Or are we looking for ways to give out more Necromancer and Populist badges?

(Okay, I has ranted and feels better now. Feel free to ignore me.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you're not referring to the home page default, which is active? That would be affected by old retags, as those are edits.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/

The actual hot tab would never show a 6 month old question.

https://photo.stackexchange.com/?tab=hot

Answer (score 1):

Ya, I think there's a good bit of re-tagging going on, especially with tag badges showing up.  LOTS of old questions suddenly getting re-tagged.

Comment: Someone must be angling for picking up some of the badges in the 'editing' category. :-)

Comment: @JayLancePhotography: While that's possible, I suspect that it's far more likely that certain people are gunning for tag badges.

Comment: Lol. Probably. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Another thought, this could be related to the new ability for "anyone can edit".

Read about it on the blog [here](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/), or on meta [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-does-peer-review-for-edits-work/76284#76284).